# Inlay hints and hover information not working in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust, rust-analyzer

I'm learning Rust and I'm using VSCode on Linux. I have this project:

```
.
├── src
│   ├── 01_hello_world
│   │   ├── comm.rs
│   │   └── mod.rs
│   └── main.rs
├── target
├── Cargo.lock
└── Cargo.toml
```

Inlay hints and hover information work fine on *main.rs* but not for the other files, why? The same occurs if I have this structure

```
...
│   ├── 01_hello_world
│   │   ├── comments
│   │   │   └── mod.rs
│   │   └── mod.rs
...
```

Comment: What do you have in your main.rs?

Comment: ```fn main() {  let x = 5;
  println!("Hello, world!");
}```

Comment: Then of course you won't get rust-analyzer support on the other files, you haven't declare them as modules.

Comment: I just want to run each file independently from each other

Comment: You need to have a different crate for each then.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a project with many independently runnable programs, it should be laid out like this:

```
.
├── src
│   └── bin
│       ├── 01_hello_world
│       │   ├── comm.rs
│       │   └── main.rs
│       └── 02_another_thing
│           └── main.rs
├── target
├── Cargo.lock
└── Cargo.toml
```

- Each program's (binary target's) root file is `src/bin/NAME/main.rs`.
- You run them like `cargo run --bin 01_hello_world`.
- There is no need for a `src/main.rs`, but if you want, you can create a `src/lib.rs` that contains code that any of them can use.